# Android: null exception when call findviewbyid

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, when I call findViewById in a TextView throws NullPointerException, but not for the others elements. I've tried anything (change identifiers, call on OnCreateView, Clean and Build the project) and I don't Know what to do.

This is my Activity

```
    public class RoutesActivity extends Activity {    

ListView routesList;
EditText searchTxt;
TextView noneRouteTxt;
long uuid;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_routes);

    noneRouteTxt = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.notroute_txt);
    getControls();
    Bundle extra = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    getRoutesList(extra);
}
```

and this is my layout: activity_routes.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.geochild.app.com.geochild.app.activitities.RoutesActivity">    

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background_waves"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/routes_listview"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_routes"
        android:id="@+id/notroute_txt"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Post the stack trace, and also indicate which line(s) in your code are being referred to.

Comment: Make sure that for every layout 'activity_routes' in res/layout, res/layout-v14, etc, you have notroute_txt defined. Otherwise, you will get NPE if it uses a layout that doesnt have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE will be obviously thrown in the following line. But you should also present the first lines of the stack trace.

```
noneRouteTxt = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.notroute_txt);
```

And the NPE is thrown because, the layout the application is using when calling your onCreate() method is another one and not the 'activity_routes', where the id notroute_txt does not exist.

How many layouts are you using or do you have copied in your res folder?